# React const App function - Route to /home

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Depending on whether the user is registered or not, the registration or home must be shown in the url "/"

I get an error at the line:

`<Route path="/" component= {Home} exact={true}/>`

What could be the problem?

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props:
> Readonly): Route', gave the following error.
> Type '() => JSX.Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<any, any> | FunctionComponent |
> ComponentClass<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>, any>
> | FunctionComponent<...> | undefined'.
> Type '() => JSX.Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent'.
> Type 'Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(props:
> RouteProps, context?: any): Route', gave the following
> error.
> Type '() => JSX.Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<any, any> | FunctionComponent |
> ComponentClass<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, unknown>, any>
> | FunctionComponent<...> | undefined'.
> Type '() => JSX.Element | undefined' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent'.ts(2769) index.d.ts(88, 5): The expected type
> comes from property 'component' which is declared here on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Route> &
> Readonly & Readonly<...>' index.d.ts(88, 5): The expected
> type comes from property 'component' which is declared here on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Route> &
> Readonly & Readonly<...>'

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
    
      const [isReg, setIsReg] = useState(false);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if(getItem("isRegistered")==null){
        console.log(getItem("isRegistered"));
        setIsReg(true);
      }
      else{
        setIsReg(false);
      }
    }, []);
    
      if(isReg){
        return (
          <IonApp>
            <IonReactRouter>
            <IonSplitPane contentId="main" when="(min-width: 4096px)">
                  <Menu />
              <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
              <Route path="/" component= {Registro } exact={true}/>
    
              </IonRouterOutlet>
              </IonSplitPane>
            </IonReactRouter>
          </IonApp>
          );
      }
      else{
        return (
          <IonApp>
            <IonReactRouter>
            <IonSplitPane contentId="main" when="(min-width: 4096px)">
                  <Menu />
              <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
                <Route path="/" component= {Home} exact={true}/>
    
              </IonRouterOutlet>
              </IonSplitPane>
            </IonReactRouter>
          </IonApp>
          );
      }
      
    };
```

Comment: Does it throw the same error when you do it this way: 
`<Route path="/" exact={true}>
   <Home />
</Route>` ?

Comment: Thanks. With that format I get: 'Home' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its return type 'Element | undefined' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Element | null'.ts(2786)